# Other images also zoom out when i click the imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-animation

I am developing an application that captures image and then compare images. On main or first screen , I have an imageview that says click n compare. When I click it, it opens camera, captures picture and then display the image on second activity. On this second activity , I have total four imageviews and a button to capture photo. Now when I click the image, it should zoom in and when i click again it should zoom it. this works fine for first image but for other images , when I zoom out, it zooms in other images as well . Please tell me where I am wrong. I have put camera permission in Manifest file and below is the code for second activity (CompareActivity.java)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
```

/*
    *
    * @author User
    * 
     */

```
  public class CompareActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imv_compare_pic_1, imv_compare_pic_2, imv_compare_pic_3,
        imv_compare_pic_4;
Button btn_capture_photo;
int count = 0;
boolean[] pressed = { false, false, false, false };
Animation zoomin, zoomout;

    /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * 
    * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
    */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compare);
    imv_compare_pic_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_compare_pic_1);
    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("image");
    imv_compare_pic_1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    /*
     * this variable is to check the number of images that have been placed
     * in activity. Since one image has been set, count is incremented to 1
     */
    count = 1;

    // zoom in and zoom out
    zoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
    zoomin.setFillAfter(true);
    zoomout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomout);

    imv_compare_pic_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /*
             * pressed[0] is false because first image hasn't been clicked
             * so it will zoom in
             */
            if (!pressed[0]) {
                imv_compare_pic_1.startAnimation(zoomin);
                pressed[0] = !pressed[0];

            } else {
                // Now pressed[0] is true so it will start zoom out
                // animation
                imv_compare_pic_1.startAnimation(zoomout);
                pressed[0] = !pressed[0];

            }
        }
    });

    btn_capture_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
    btn_capture_photo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            open();
        }
    });
}

public void open() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    if (count == 1) {
        imv_compare_pic_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_compare_pic_2);
        imv_compare_pic_2.setImageBitmap(bp);
        count = 2;
        // set zoom in and zoom out on the event of onclick
        // imv_compare_pic_2.setAnimation(zoomin);
        // imv_compare_pic_2.setAnimation(zoomout);
        imv_compare_pic_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!pressed[1]) {
                    imv_compare_pic_2.startAnimation(zoomin);
                    pressed[1] = !pressed[1];

                } else {
                    imv_compare_pic_2.startAnimation(zoomout);
                    pressed[1] = !pressed[1];

                }
            }
        });

    }

    else if (count == 2) {
        imv_compare_pic_3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_compare_pic_3);
        imv_compare_pic_3.setImageBitmap(bp);
        count = 3;

        // set zoom in and zoom out on the event of onclick
        // imv_compare_pic_3.setAnimation(zoomin);
        // imv_compare_pic_3.setAnimation(zoomout);

        imv_compare_pic_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!pressed[2]) {
                    imv_compare_pic_3.startAnimation(zoomin);
                    pressed[2] = !pressed[2];

                } else {
                    imv_compare_pic_3.startAnimation(zoomout);
                    pressed[2] = !pressed[2];
                }
            }
        });

    } else if (count == 3) {
        imv_compare_pic_4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_compare_pic_4);
        imv_compare_pic_4.setImageBitmap(bp);
        count = 4;
        // btn_capture_photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // set zoom in and zoom out on the event of onclick
        // imv_compare_pic_4.setAnimation(zoomin);
        // imv_compare_pic_4.setAnimation(zoomout);
        imv_compare_pic_4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!pressed[3]) {
                    imv_compare_pic_4.startAnimation(zoomin);
                    pressed[3] = !pressed[3];
                } else {
                    imv_compare_pic_4.startAnimation(zoomout);
                    pressed[3] = !pressed[3];
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try using `zoomin.setFillAfter(true);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. where do I have to add this line?

Comment: After `zoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);` before you start animation.

Comment: I added the line but the problem still persists. The zoom out animation works fine only for the first time. For remaining images, all images first zoom in and then zoom out. What I am not getting is that when I have applied separate animation for different imageviews, then why it is zooming in other images when I have to zoom out only the selected image?

Comment: That may be due to count variable. all images are animated together, right?

Comment: Yeah i want to place my image in a particular imageview that is why I have placed count variable. When count is 1 , it places image on second imageview and so on and this continues for four images only but the problem occurs only when I click the zoomed in image so that it zooms out. Is there any problem in my logic?

Comment: Please debug and check which code is being executed and what are values of state at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing count just after starting animation.

Plus you are maintaining just one boolean for `pressed` state.

I would suggest you use an array for boolean, as you would need `pressed` state for particular imageview.

Something like:

```
//in onCreate 
boolean[] pressed = {false, false, false, false};

//an example for one imageview
...
else if (count == 2) {
    imv_compare_pic_3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_compare_pic_3);
    imv_compare_pic_3.setImageBitmap(bp);
    count = 3;

    // set zoom in and zoom out on the event of onclick
    //imv_compare_pic_3.setAnimation(zoomin);
    //imv_compare_pic_3.setAnimation(zoomout);

    imv_compare_pic_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (!pressed[2]) {
                imv_compare_pic_3.startAnimation(zoomin);
                pressed[2] = !pressed[2];
            } else {
                imv_compare_pic_3.startAnimation(zoomout);
                pressed[2] = !pressed[2];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please recheck your count. As its 1 to 4, I would suggest to change it from 0 to 3. So it would be easy to use with boolean array indexes.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and took the pressed variable in array but still all images animate simultaneously. I even tried this by making separate variables for all images but no success. count variable only maintains the number of images that have been captured. If two images have been captured, the third image will be placed in third imageview that is why I have kept this variable and pressed is placed to check whether the image has been clicked or zoomed in. All images are animating simultaneously. If i use clearAnimation() , the image does not zoom out

Comment: Please update question with current code. @user1801962

Comment: I resolved the issue by making separate xml files for zoomout. Now when I zoom out any imageview, the other ones do not animate. It may not be an exact solution but just a workaround to resolve this issue. Thanks anyways for your help